# resource files are coming up empty when hosted locally

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, xampp

i am working on a spa app. It was working fine online. When i tried it in my localhost of xampp, all the library files were empty.

This is the structure of the app

```
--html_source
|--vendors
   |--bootstrap
      |--bootstrap.min.css
|--index.html
```

i start xampp and open this in my localhost. Check the source files in the
"inspect element" of browser but shows all the files in the vendor folder as empty files.

Need suggestions

Comment: Check `.htaccess`. Smells like url rewriting

Comment: can u elaborate a bit. Would be helpful

Comment: Can a find a file named `.htaccess`? If yes, update with the contents.