# XAMPP/Localhost external Javascript File empty

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, xampp, localhost

I've set up a website with XAMPP, have working on some PHP things and now tried to include some Javascript functions. My index.php is in the htdocs folder. In that htdocsfolder, I have a JS folder with a scripts.js file. The file shows up in my Sources when inspecting the website in my browser, but it is completely empty.

I have the following line in the head of my index file:

```
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

I found this question:
[resource files are coming up empty when hosted locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935644/resource-files-are-coming-up-empty-when-hosted-locally)

People mention it might be an htaccess problem. I don't know anything about htaccess. There is currently no htaccess file in my htdocs folder.

Code in my scripts.js file:

```
alert("Hi!");

function toggle(element, show) {
    document.getElementById(element).style.display = show;
}

function toggleLogin() {
    toggle('registerWrapper', 'none');
    toggle('loginWrapper', 'block');
}

function toggleRegister() {
    toggle('loginWrapper', 'none');
    toggle('registerWrapper', 'block');
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: is your file there ? is there any error in your console ?

Comment: The file shows up in the Sources, but it's empty. There are no errors in the console, until I start using functions that are supposed to be in the empty file.

Comment: what code is in your script file which is not showing up?

Comment: Added scripts.js content to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give that file full permissions just to see if that is your issue. Then lower it if that is a case.

Also see if the file owner is as your xampp expects (or as other files are)

Comment: I don't know anything about permissions unforunately :(

Comment: can you go into console -> network -> select file on the left -> and see what code or error you get there.. somethink like this: https://i.imgur.com/OrvLPVt.png

Comment: Status code for scripts.js is 200 OK (from memory cache).

Comment: the I guess that some server issue you have,, but again you get 200 OK replay what is very puzzling :(